# How to obtain a user ID and OAuth access token in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, account-linking

In a webhook (written in [Java](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-java)), as part of an action configured for [account linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in-oauth?oauth=code) with the following topology:

```
Actions-on-Google->Dialogflow->Webhook,
```

I am trying to extract the **userId** and OAuth **accessToken** from the incoming requests.

Both initial request (before the linking flow is started):

```
[java] 02-25-2019 16:41:33 [qtp2056234595-232] INFO  domain.lola.user.utils.http.ControllerUtils [toString:30]    - Received AoG Request {
 [java]   "responseId": "8da3a8c2-2d60-4675-b249-a39bbc1840c9",
 [java]   "queryResult": {
 [java]     "queryText": "GOOGLE_ASSISTANT_WELCOME",
 [java]     "parameters": {
 [java]       "any": ""
 [java]     },
 [java]     "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
 [java]     "fulfillmentMessages": [{
 [java]       "text": {
 [java]         "text": [""]
 [java]       }
 [java]     }],
 [java]     "outputContexts": [{
 [java]       "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHEEjeH_tnJt20xAXWhtglLPVUHLgTuf1WVfDzN_FGr46jKppLq3P--zPd3g-3890FJu7hErWAdOZAQeBg/contexts/google_assistant_welcome",
 [java]       "parameters": {
 [java]         "any.original": "",
 [java]         "any": ""
 [java]       }
 [java]     }, {
 [java]       "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHEEjeH_tnJt20xAXWhtglLPVUHLgTuf1WVfDzN_FGr46jKppLq3P--zPd3g-3890FJu7hErWAdOZAQeBg/contexts/actions_capability_screen_output",
 [java]       "parameters": {
 [java]         "any.original": "",
 [java]         "any": ""
 [java]       }
 [java]     }, {
 [java]       "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHEEjeH_tnJt20xAXWhtglLPVUHLgTuf1WVfDzN_FGr46jKppLq3P--zPd3g-3890FJu7hErWAdOZAQeBg/contexts/google_assistant_input_type_voice",
 [java]       "parameters": {
 [java]         "any.original": "",
 [java]         "any": ""
 [java]       }
 [java]     }, {
 [java]       "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHEEjeH_tnJt20xAXWhtglLPVUHLgTuf1WVfDzN_FGr46jKppLq3P--zPd3g-3890FJu7hErWAdOZAQeBg/contexts/actions_capability_audio_output",
 [java]       "parameters": {
 [java]         "any.original": "",
 [java]         "any": ""
 [java]       }
 [java]     }, {
 [java]       "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHEEjeH_tnJt20xAXWhtglLPVUHLgTuf1WVfDzN_FGr46jKppLq3P--zPd3g-3890FJu7hErWAdOZAQeBg/contexts/actions_capability_media_response_audio",
 [java]       "parameters": {
 [java]         "any.original": "",
 [java]         "any": ""
 [java]       }
 [java]     }, {
 [java]       "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHEEjeH_tnJt20xAXWhtglLPVUHLgTuf1WVfDzN_FGr46jKppLq3P--zPd3g-3890FJu7hErWAdOZAQeBg/contexts/actions_capability_web_browser",
 [java]       "parameters": {
 [java]         "any.original": "",
 [java]         "any": ""
 [java]       }
 [java]     }],
 [java]     "intent": {
 [java]       "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/intents/f645f492-f6dc-4e7e-8da6-45711c654ad0",
 [java]       "displayName": "RawText"
 [java]     },
 [java]     "intentDetectionConfidence": 1.0,
 [java]     "languageCode": "en-us"
 [java]   },
 [java]   "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
 [java]     "source": "google",
 [java]     "version": "2",
 [java]     "payload": {
 [java]       "isInSandbox": true,
 [java]       "surface": {
 [java]         "capabilities": [{
 [java]           "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
 [java]         }, {
 [java]           "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"
 [java]         }, {
 [java]           "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
 [java]         }, {
 [java]           "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
 [java]         }]
 [java]       },
 [java]       "inputs": [{
 [java]         "rawInputs": [{
 [java]           "query": "open speech Bank",
 [java]           "inputType": "VOICE"
 [java]         }],
 [java]         "intent": "actions.intent.MAIN"
 [java]       }],
 [java]       "user": {
 [java]         "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}",
 [java]         "lastSeen": "2019-02-25T16:40:39Z",
 [java]         "locale": "en-US",
 [java]         "userId": "ABwppHFQHUBr0RrWA_OuL-kK2sxTPUvQtL3D-x2Ydr-7uxLt9zzEFzJrGB-X96d9XY8k9XTJj-RUg9WpzGB9jg"
 [java]       },
 [java]       "conversation": {
 [java]         "conversationId": "ABwppHEEjeH_tnJt20xAXWhtglLPVUHLgTuf1WVfDzN_FGr46jKppLq3P--zPd3g-3890FJu7hErWAdOZAQeBg",
 [java]         "type": "NEW"
 [java]       },
 [java]       "availableSurfaces": [{
 [java]         "capabilities": [{
 [java]           "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
 [java]         }, {
 [java]           "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
 [java]         }, {
 [java]           "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
 [java]         }]
 [java]       }]
 [java]     }
 [java]   },
 [java]   "session": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHEEjeH_tnJt20xAXWhtglLPVUHLgTuf1WVfDzN_FGr46jKppLq3P--zPd3g-3890FJu7hErWAdOZAQeBg"
 [java] }
```

and the post-linking one:

```
 [java]   "responseId": "2aa05bec-9fd3-4387-8e87-ef70509395db",
 [java]   "queryResult": {
 [java]     "queryText": "actions_intent_SIGN_IN",
 [java]     "parameters": {
 [java]     },
 [java]     "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
 [java]     "fulfillmentMessages": [{
 [java]       "text": {
 [java]         "text": [""]
 [java]       }
 [java]     }],
 [java]     "outputContexts": [{
 [java]       "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHEEjeH_tnJt20xAXWhtglLPVUHLgTuf1WVfDzN_FGr46jKppLq3P--zPd3g-3890FJu7hErWAdOZAQeBg/contexts/actions_capability_screen_output"
 [java]     }, {
 [java]       "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHEEjeH_tnJt20xAXWhtglLPVUHLgTuf1WVfDzN_FGr46jKppLq3P--zPd3g-3890FJu7hErWAdOZAQeBg/contexts/actions_intent_sign_in",
 [java]       "parameters": {
 [java]         "SIGN_IN": {
 [java]           "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.SignInValue",
 [java]           "status": "OK"
 [java]         },
 [java]         "text": ""
 [java]       }
 [java]     }, {
 [java]       "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHEEjeH_tnJt20xAXWhtglLPVUHLgTuf1WVfDzN_FGr46jKppLq3P--zPd3g-3890FJu7hErWAdOZAQeBg/contexts/_actions_on_google",
 [java]       "lifespanCount": 98,
 [java]       "parameters": {
 [java]         "data": "{}"
 [java]       }
 [java]     }, {
 [java]       "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHEEjeH_tnJt20xAXWhtglLPVUHLgTuf1WVfDzN_FGr46jKppLq3P--zPd3g-3890FJu7hErWAdOZAQeBg/contexts/actions_capability_audio_output"
 [java]     }, {
 [java]       "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHEEjeH_tnJt20xAXWhtglLPVUHLgTuf1WVfDzN_FGr46jKppLq3P--zPd3g-3890FJu7hErWAdOZAQeBg/contexts/actions_capability_media_response_audio"
 [java]     }, {
 [java]       "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHEEjeH_tnJt20xAXWhtglLPVUHLgTuf1WVfDzN_FGr46jKppLq3P--zPd3g-3890FJu7hErWAdOZAQeBg/contexts/actions_capability_web_browser"
 [java]     }],
 [java]     "intent": {
 [java]       "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/intents/88bbeb61-b612-47b1-b0e5-8d0de392a0c3",
 [java]       "displayName": "SignInIntent"
 [java]     },
 [java]     "intentDetectionConfidence": 1.0,
 [java]     "languageCode": "en-us"
 [java]   },
 [java]   "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
 [java]     "source": "google",
 [java]     "version": "2",
 [java]     "payload": {
 [java]       "isInSandbox": true,
 [java]       "surface": {
 [java]         "capabilities": [{
 [java]           "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
 [java]         }, {
 [java]           "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
 [java]         }, {
 [java]           "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
 [java]         }, {
 [java]           "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"
 [java]         }]
 [java]       },
 [java]       "inputs": [{
 [java]         "rawInputs": [{
 [java]         }],
 [java]         "arguments": [{
 [java]           "extension": {
 [java]             "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.SignInValue",
 [java]             "status": "OK"
 [java]           },
 [java]           "name": "SIGN_IN"
 [java]         }, {
 [java]           "name": "text"
 [java]         }],
 [java]         "intent": "actions.intent.SIGN_IN"
 [java]       }],
 [java]       "user": {
 [java]         "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}",
 [java]         "lastSeen": "2019-02-25T16:40:39Z",
 [java]         "accessToken": "token1",
 [java]         "locale": "en-US",
 [java]         "userId": "ABwppHFQHUBr0RrWA_OuL-kK2sxTPUvQtL3D-x2Ydr-7uxLt9zzEFzJrGB-X96d9XY8k9XTJj-RUg9WpzGB9jg"
 [java]       },
 [java]       "conversation": {
 [java]         "conversationId": "ABwppHEEjeH_tnJt20xAXWhtglLPVUHLgTuf1WVfDzN_FGr46jKppLq3P--zPd3g-3890FJu7hErWAdOZAQeBg",
 [java]         "type": "ACTIVE",
 [java]         "conversationToken": "[\"_actions_on_google\"]"
 [java]       },
 [java]       "availableSurfaces": [{
 [java]         "capabilities": [{
 [java]           "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
 [java]         }, {
 [java]           "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
 [java]         }, {
 [java]           "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
 [java]         }]
 [java]       }]
 [java]     }
 [java]   },
 [java]   "session": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHEEjeH_tnJt20xAXWhtglLPVUHLgTuf1WVfDzN_FGr46jKppLq3P--zPd3g-3890FJu7hErWAdOZAQeBg"
 [java] }
```

seem to contain the `userId` field.  The `accessToken` only starts appearing after the linking, which is correct.

However, in my webhook, in both cases I'm using the following to capture the `userId` and `accessToken` (aside from other things):

```
private void logUserDetails(ActionRequest request) {

    String userId = request.getAppRequest().getUser().getUserId();
    log.info("request.getAppRequest().getUser().getUserId()={}",userId);

    String idToken = request.getUser().getIdToken();
    log.info("idToken={}",idToken);

    String usrId = request.getUser().getUserId();
    log.info("request.getUser().getUserId()={}",usrId);

    String queryText = request.getWebhookRequest().getQueryResult().getQueryText();
    log.info("queryText={}", queryText);
}
```

and in both cases I'm seeing them both returned as `null`:

pre account linking:

```
[java] 02-25-2019 16:41:33  INFO  AoGApp [logUserDetails:23]    - request.getAppRequest().getUser().getUserId()=null
 [java] 02-25-2019 16:41:33  INFO  AoGApp [logUserDetails:26]    - idToken=null
 [java] 02-25-2019 16:41:33  INFO  AoGApp [logUserDetails:29]    - request.getUser().getUserId()=null
 [java] 02-25-2019 16:41:33  INFO  AoGApp [logUserDetails:32]    - queryText=GOOGLE_ASSISTANT_WELCOME
```

post account linking:

```
[java] 02-25-2019 16:43:25  INFO  AoGApp [logUserDetails:23]    - request.getAppRequest().getUser().getUserId()=null
     [java] 02-25-2019 16:43:25  INFO  AoGApp [logUserDetails:26]    - idToken=null
     [java] 02-25-2019 16:43:25  INFO  AoGApp [logUserDetails:29]    - request.getUser().getUserId()=null
     [java] 02-25-2019 16:43:25  INFO  AoGApp [logUserDetails:32]    - queryText=actions_intent_SIGN_IN
```

Via the Java API, `queryText` seems to be **the only one** extracting the actual value, but not so for the other fields from the incoming requests, where they are all `null`.

I have a couple of questions:

- At what point does the `userId` get created by Google and what triggers its creation?  In other words, would there be a case where the `userId` in the request is actually `null`, before its value has been generated, will I ever be able to see such situation in the request coming into my webhook?
- How can I extract other fields from the request coming into my webhook?  What am I doing wrong such that parsing the request via Java API returns different results than the values seen on a raw request?

Comment: Are you using Google Sign-In, OAuth, or both?

Comment: We are using only OAuth.